# hook_user_insert not being called

Tags: 8, users, hooks

I've got a custom module `weekly_digest` and I want to make it so each new user is added to a table with info on their subscription preferences.

I've been using the admin UI to add the users to test, unsure if that effects things but I don't see why it would.

As some context, in my .module I currently have `weekly_digest_node_insert` and that works just fine.

And here is the function which does not get executed and I can't get Xdebug to catch it either:

```
function weekly_digest_user_insert(UserInterface $entity) {

  $query = Drupal::database()->insert('weekly_digest_user_preferences');
  $query->fields([
    'uid',
  ])->useDefaults([
    'new_posts',
    'digests',
  ])->values([
    $entity->id(),
  ])->execute();

}
```

Most search results returned "Can't in theme" or "Drupal 7" so I was unable to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you are using the incorrect argument. `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert` is a generic hook, it's not opinionated about what entity you are "inserting" (E.g. it could be a node, taxonomy, user...)

Try:

```
function weekly_digest_user_insert(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Are you saying I should change my parameter type to an EntityInterface?

Comment: Yes, unless I am mistaken, I believe that is the correct approach.

Comment: I will try this out tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: Yep that worked. I know I've seen others use UserInterface there but perhaps it was a drupal 7 site or something.